# tableview cell for Row at index path Query

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

i want to call table view  cell for row at index path explicitly outside.can any one help me out.i have called using [table view object Cell for Row at index path];

Answer (score 1):

Simple reload the table view by default  table delegate methods will fire.

```
[self.tableview1 reload];
```

If you want to refresh the particular cell just use this :

```
[self.tableView1 beginUpdates];

[self.tableView1 reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.tableView1 endUpdates];
```

Comment: i am unable to access index path outside the delegate methods .

Comment: if you want to access the index out of the delegate method just declare one local instance and assign the selected instance to the instance and use.